# Deploy a proxy service created in the WSO2 Developer Studio in the ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I created a WSO2 proxy service using WSO2 Developer studio and would like to deploy it in the ESB in my local machine. If I create a CAR file and deploy it as in https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Deploying+a+C-App, it doesn't get deployed as a Proxy service. How can I deploy it as a proxy service?

Answer (score 3):

This works without any problems. The only problem that I might think of, is that the proxy has the wrong server role assigned in the pom of the car project. To check this, do the following.

1. Click on the pom.xml of the car project
2. in the appearing form, check that in the dependency part the project you want to deploy is checked
3. expand the proxy artifact in the dependency view and verify that ServerRole is set to EnterpriseServiceBus
4. save if you have made any changes, create the car and deploy it

Hope that helps.

Regards
Martin